# how to find partial link in a webpage through selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to fetch and print few links from the webpage that contains starting text say `href="/incidents/types/...."`.

I am using this code as mentioned below:

```
List<WebElement> linksize = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement myElement : linksize){
WebElement link = myElement.findElement(By.partialLinkText("href=\"/incidents/types/\""));
System.out.println(link);
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance,
Neeraj

Comment: Are you looking for the link*Text* or a part of the URL the link refers to?

Comment: @Neeraj Tried an of the proposed solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

The proper usage of the By.partialLinkText is descrived here:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Esample:

Html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=cheese">search for cheese</a>>
```

Code:

```
WebElement cheese = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("cheese"));
```

So your code should be:

```
WebElement link = myElement.findElement(By.partialLinkText("/incidents/types"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch elements which contain the given href, you can go with...

```
List<WebElement> lnkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
List<WebElement> lnkMatch = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
for ( WebElement ele : lnkElements ) {
    if ( ele.getAttribute("href").contains("/incidents/types") ){
        System.out.println(ele.getText()); // Prints text in link
        lnkMatch.add(ele); // Adds element containing the links
    }
}
```